# what is score in princomp

Tags: matlab, pca

I have a CSV file containing features. The rows represent objects and columns represents features. I read the CSV file like this

```
O = csvread('data');
```

Now i did a

```
[COEFF,SCORE] = princomp(O)
```

My goal in doing a princomp on O is to perform dimensionality reduction as the no of features is too large. Now after this operation does the SCORE vector hold the dimensionality reduced feature set  or do i have to perform some more operations to get it ?

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/princomp.html):

> [COEFF,SCORE] = princomp(X) returns SCORE, the principal component scores; that is, the representation of X in the principal component space. Rows of SCORE correspond to observations, columns to components.

Comment: so score vector is the data vector that i have to input to the classifier right ?

Comment: Yes, it's the data vector in this transformed space.

Comment: if the input vector in this case = O contains 9 columns, I know that the column significance of SCORE vector decreases as you go from left to right but do not know how to decide how many of them to use.

Comment: If you take a third return variable `latent`, that shows you the variance accounted for by each column; `cumsum(latent) ./ sum(latent)` gives you the percentages. Choose a `k` that best balances between not too many features and covering a bunch of the variance; then just take the first `k` components of each vector. (To transform test data, just slice `coeff` appropriately.) The documentation I linked to above has examples of this.

Comment: i got these results after i did  cumsum(latent)./sum(latent) 0.9937
    0.9973
    0.9988
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000

if i need 98% variance i need to select the first three columns right ?

Comment: Actually, it looks like the first column alone gives you 99.37% of the variance!

Comment: how do i determine which of the input features contributes most for classification ?

Comment: Look at the first column of `coeff`; that's the linear combination of the features that gives you so much of the variance.

Comment: from that how do i decide. Could you please help me

Comment: Say the column is `[ 0 1 0 0 .3  0 0 0 0 ]` (it won't be so clean) chat would mean that the second feature plus .3 times the fifth feature gives you basically all the variance; the others are either useless or don't give any additional information. More likely, all of the columns will have some weight; if the features are all scaled the same, very roughly bigger-magnitude coefficient means more important. Of course, if the features are cheap to compute, you could also just do all of them and then combine them into a single number with those weights for the classifier.